# Macro or function to construct a float (double) from a given sign, mantissa and exponent?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, double

Is there any macro or function to construct a float (double) from a given sign, mantissa and exponent (all binary or decimal) that either returns a valid float (double) number or returns NaN if the number specified by input is not representable as float (double)?

Comment: I don't know of any standard macro or function, but it would be pretty easy to create one.  For example, if your mantissa is a signed integer, then multiply this by pow(base,exponent).

Comment: Any math operation is suspected to change the result, so the binary representation of the result won't be identical to the given components.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `ldexp`.

Comment: Note that ldexp(1.0,1024) returns inf, and ldexp(1.0,-1075) will return 0.0 and ldexp(3.0,-1075) will round upper to ldexp(4.0,-1075)... They are not representable (exactly) but you won't get a NaN.