# constructing a float from sign mantissa and exponent

Tags: c++, floating-point

Is there a way to build any float given its components (unsigned integers)?

I noticed ldexp in math.h which does mantissa * 2^exponent but this doesnt help for some decimal values, such as 0.25 whose representation is

0 01111101 00000000000000000000000

The mantissa is 0 thus ldexp would return 0 and not 0.25. Is there a way around this?

Edit: What are the actual values of the mantissa and exponent, considering the hidden bit? I.E. - what values would be fed into ldexpf?

Comment: Given that your variable is `unsigned int x`, you can break strict aliasing rule and initialize the variable `float f = *((float*)&x)`. Just make sure that `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(float)` on your platform.

Comment: Your final conclusion is wrong. The mantissa is one bit longer than the stored value. The so-called *hidden bit* is an implied 1, which you ignored, and wrongfully concluded, that the mantissa is 0.

Comment: BTW, function `ldexp` is for `double` (8 bytes), function `ldexpf` is for `float` (4 bytes). Using function `ldexp` on a `float` operand might be the source of the problem that you're experiencing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Macro or function to construct a float (double) from a given sign, mantissa and exponent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639375/macro-or-function-to-construct-a-float-double-from-a-given-sign-mantissa-and)

Comment: What do you mean hidden bit? do you mean that bit 23 (the first bit of the exponent) still belongs to the mantissa and the exponent makes up bits 24-30 or there is an implied bit between bits 22 and 23? In either case, what's the value of the mantissa then?

Comment: The implied `1` is not stored in memory. It is in between bits 22 and 23. See [IEEE 754: Representation and encoding in memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Representation_and_encoding_in_memory): *"In particular, in the normal range, the leading bit of the significand is non-zero, thus always 1. As a consequence, this leading bit 1 of the normal numbers need not be represented in the memory encoding."*

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the floating point encoding on your machine. A common one is IEEE754, if you give a look you can have an idea of the task. Anyway keep n mind that is platform dependent.